# How to wrap a class that has generic type methods with a class that has a generic type and no generic type arguments on the methods?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, generic-method

I have the following code example:

```js
class Stupid {
  private cache: Map<any, any> = new Map();
  get<T>(key: string): T {
    return this.cache.get(key);
  };
}

class Smart<T> extends Stupid {
  get(key: string): T {
    super.get<T>(key);
  }
}
```

I have valid reasons for wrapping the Stupid class (other than the generics) which are not apparent in this barebone reproduction of the problem, nonetheless I would like to know if this is somehow possible.

Please also note that the class Stupid is a node dependency. I can't change that implementation.

The purpose would be to not have a generic type argument on each method, but to move it to the wrapping class (class Smart) and use that in super calls, to provide the required generic to the extended class (class Stupid).

Please feel free to use this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuBXADgSwCbQN4ChrWQCdUA3MeAU2mDGAAsKAuaAWTGQB4wA7ATwBpoPXgD5oAXmjcKAd1bsAFAEoA3HmgBzCvA4AVEQoDWFXswjxi3DUua7s6-IW2JC3aPDqoIAOhr0K3lrwRiaq6gC+auE4OKCQMLAAtmCEOvrQFAAelNzoCUhomLj4QSGm0OaW1rb2+PgQKBSEgdp6Bsa8YfjR4UA) for experimentation.

Comment: This is not possible because `Stupid.get()` says it returns any type the *caller* wants, while `Smart<T>.get()` can only return the type `T` the *implementer* chose. Those are mismatches so what you're asking for is inconsistent.  Indeed it's essentially impossible to implement `<T>(key: string)=>T` safely so it's not surprising you'd have an issue.  You'll need a type assertion or the equivalent somewhere if you want to do this, perhaps as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WJV4ZW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: As far as I can tell it does answer the question, so thank you very much. If you do write up an answer, please explain in more detail what you're doing there with the Smarter interface and the FakeSmart implementation. I'm not sure i understand the code example entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get()` method in `Stupid` has the problematic [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature `<T>(key: string) => T`, which means that it will return a value of any type `T` that the *caller* specifies.  This is demonstrably impossible:

```
const stupid = new Stupid();
const n = stupid.get<number>("xyz");
// const n: number
const s = stupid.get<string>("xyz");
// const s: string
```

In the above, you're calling `stupid.get("xyz")` twice at runtime, but the compiler thinks the first call returns a `number` and the second one returns a `string`, which is exceptionally unlikely.  The only reason the method implementation type checks is because the return type of `cache.get()` is the intentionally unsafe [`any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).

Let's not worry too much about the type safety of `Stupid.get()` and instead look at the problem you're having when subclassing it:

---

```
class Smart<T> extends Stupid {
  get(key: string): T { // error!
    return super.get<T>(key);
  }
}

const smart: Smart<number> = new Smart();
const n = smart.get("xyz");
// const n: number
```

The reason that doesn't work is because subclasses must be assignable to their superclasses.  If `Smart<T> extends Stupid`, then every `Smart<T>` instance is *also* a `Stupid` instance, and should be usable accordingly:

```
const stupid: Stupid = smart; // this should be allowed
const s = stupid.get<string>("xyz"); 
// const s: string // uh oh
```

`Smart<number>.get()` returns a `number`, but `Stupid.get()` returns any type the caller wants, such as `string`.  These are not compatible behaviors, and so the compiler complains.  If you want `Smart` to truly be a subclass of `Stupid`, you'd need to make `get()` generic the same way as it is in `Stupid`, which is not what you're trying to do.

---

So how can we proceed?  Presumably we shouldn't worry too much about type safety, since there's no way to guarantee that `get()` returns the proper type for either `Stupid` or `Smart`.  Instead we will just do what's necessary to make it compile.  Usually that will require something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that some value is of some type.

Here's one way to do it:

```
interface Smart<T> {
  get(key: string): T
}

const FakeSmart = Stupid as new <T>() => ISmart<T>;

class Smart<T> extends FakeSmart<T> {
  get(key: string): T {
    return super.get(key);
  }
}
```

What we're doing is pretending that `Stupid` behaves like `Smart`.  First we create an `ISmart<T>` interface which is the same as `Stupid` except that the generic is moved to where you want it.  Then we assign the `Stupid` constructor to a new variable called `FakeSmart` and *assert* that `FakeSmart` has the type of a generic [constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  So `FakeSmart` is just `Stupid` at runtime, but the compiler thinks it is of a proper superclass of `Smart<T>`.

And then we declare that `Smart<T> extends FakeSmart<T>`.  At runtime this is that same as your original code, but now at compile time there are no errors because the `get()` method of `Smart<T>` is compatible with the `get()` method of `FakeSmart<T>`.  Note that the call `super.get(key)` doesn't take a type argument because `FakeSmart.get()` doesn't take a type argument.

---

So there you go.  Personally I'd be worried about code like this where you can tell the compiler simultaneous contradictory things about the types, but if you're not the one writing `Stupid` then I guess the best you can do is wrap it in something more reasonable.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=41&pln=21&pc=42#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuBXADgSwCbQN4ChrWQCdUA3MeAU2mDGAAsKAuaAWTGQB4wA7ATwBpoPXgD5oAXmjcKAd1bsAFAEoA3HmgBzCvA4AVEQoDWFXswjxi3DUua7s6-IW2JC3aPDqoIAOhr0K3lrwRiaq6gC+auE4OMAA9tzm0OYoGBJSsnBIaOjKavGJ8FLpKTmB2hzciAC2AEYUhAYARAAevABeTWEA9N3UCUnczFV1DbEDRTCSpRjlOuaWGs1tnT19BUkQZhaoVjHcYNUUEMi0VABycchUuPigkDCw1WCEOvrQFC2U3OiP2Wm3fCabQhUzJHZWGzQOxYaC9D6EQhxQgAQgcQKcSFcyRQDTmegMxl4YSB0Gi+Gi6g2k2er2YTxeOhG9Ua6WkcgZrzyVImxWmtPgcwUrQ6XTU+Hh1KkwxqLJid15M3Q9P+mH5jPF-UKyRKqvxC12S2FKzF6kliu2ixwlJwu0ohAAZmdoABJTlvMSAoKgy2GqG6a3jbUAMTAxnd6QQqUwkAycgJygkYjdAoJali4CgcFT70+31+0FD4ZznvU3qJvshtnspMxLjcEFxhCFRJJZOtQA)

Comment: Thank you for the details explanation. I think at this point (since i mostly have to redeclare all methods Stupid potentially has) I'm better off declaring a private property in Smart with a new Instance of Stupid and drop the "extends Stupid". Basically just wrap Stupid entirely.
The resulting code would be more maintainable than the typing gymnastics you proposed, which, don't get me wrong ... it's an elegant solution given the question, but like you said, when you get to write such code, it starts to beg the question ... should i really? :)
What do you think @jcalz?

Comment: I agree.  You *might* be able to programmatically generate the `Smart` type from `Stupid`, but yeah, dropping `extends` could be much easier, especially if you were going to override each method anyway; `this.stupid` isn't much harder to write than `super` anyway.